# TraditionalForm of a polynomial two variables

Tags: output-formatting, traditional-form

I want to write the expression $$x  - x (-x^2 -  5 x) + m x - x^2$$ in the form $$x^3+4 x^2  + (m+1) x.$$
I tried

```
TraditionalForm[Collect[x  - x (-x^2 -  5 x) + m x - x^2, x]]
```

I get

> (m+1) x+x^3+4 x^2

How to get  $x^3+4 x^2  + (m+1) x$?

Another question, I want to write the expression $x^3+(-2 m-1) x^2+(-4 m-5) x$ in the form
$$x^3 -(2 m +1) x^2 -(4 m +5) x,$$ I tried

```
TraditionalForm@PolynomialForm[x^3+(-2 m-1)x^2+(-4 m-5) x]
```

> x^3+(-2 m-1) x^2+(-4 m-5) x

Comment: `TraditionalForm@
 PolynomialForm@Collect[x - x (-x^2 - 5 x) + m x - x^2, x]`

Comment: System`PolynomialForm has no Help  entry, but most procedures are discussed in Documentation: tutorial/AlgebraicManipulation#159063065